# Vb.net program login using local admin account

Tags: vb.net, authentication, administrator

I write a program which need user login using local admin account.
But local admin account name is different for every PC, so I cannot hard code the user name.

Below code only retrieved the user in Administrators group, but not authentication. Can help?
1. How to authentication username & password? 
2. How to force user to login using local user account only.

```
        Dim localMachine As New DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" & "localhost")
        Dim admGroup As DirectoryEntry = localMachine.Children.Find("Administrators", "group")
        Dim members As Object = admGroup.Invoke("members", Nothing)
        For Each groupMember As Object In CType(members, IEnumerable)
            Dim member As New DirectoryEntry(groupMember)
            MsgBox(member.Name)
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and simplest way of ensuring that your application runs with administrative privileges is to [embed a manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) that makes just such a demand.

You should *never* hard-code anything like this, and the presence of UAC means there is no guarantee that a user who is a member of the Administrators group has administrative privileges at the moment for your process.

The VB.NET compiler embeds a default manifest into your application automatically, but that default manifest doesn't request administrative privileges. So you need to add a custom manifest that does.
To get one, follow these steps:

1. Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer.
2. Select "Properties" from the context menu.
3. Switch to the "Application" tab.
4. Click "View Windows Settings" to open the manifest file.
5. Make the following modification:

```xml
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```